# Is it possible to extend a base class in a data class without overriding parameters?

Tags: kotlin

I have a simple inheritance tree in my Kotlin project, where a base class is extended by a data class. I cannot declare construction of my data class without overriding the parameters from the base class

I've noticed that this would work if I wasn't extending in a data class:

```
open class Base(
    val first: String,
    val second: String
)

class Child(
    first: String,
    second: String,
    val third: List<String>
) : Base(first, second)
```

This is what I ended up with currently:

```
open class Base(
    open val first: String,
    open val second: String
)

data class Child(
    override val first: String,
    override val second: String,
    val third: List<String>
) : Base(first, second)
```

But I would like to be able not to override the constructor parameters, because I'm not really overriding them. I just need to take them in my Child constructor to be able to pass them to Base.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a base class like this and a derived `data` class, you have to override its properties or separate them, because all primary constructor parameters of a `data` class must also be declared as properties:

> — All primary constructor parameters need to be marked as `val` or `var`;

However, based on what your goal really is, you can transform your code in one of the following ways:

- Declare the properties in `Child` as separate, unrelated properties:

  ```
  open class Base(
      open val first: String,
      open val second: String
  )

  data class Child(
      val childFirst: String,
      val childSecond: String,
      val third: List<String>
  ) : Base(childFirst, childSecond)
  ```

  This will allow you to have separate implementations for the properties if you need it, storing the values passed as `childFirst` and `childSecond` in the `Child` and probably altering them in some way in the implementation of `Base`.
- Make `Base` an interface:

  ```
  interface Base {
      val first: String,
      val second: String
  }

  data class Child(
      override val first: String,
      override val second: String,
      val third: List<String>
  ) : Base
  ```

  This ensures that `Base` doesn't have an implementation that stores property values in addition to the `Child`'s properties with backing fields (those will consume additional memory, but, as the propeties are overridden, `Base` will consistently see the values of the `Child`'s backing fields as `first` and `second`).
- Make `Base` an abstract class with `abstract` properties:

  ```
  abstract class Base {
      abstract val first: String,
      abstract val second: String
  }

  data class Child(
      override val first: String,
      override val second: String,
      val third: List<String>
  ) : Base()
  ```

  This follows a similar purpose: `Base` won't store the property values in its implementation needlessly duplicating the properties of `Child`.
- Make `Child` a normal class, manually implementing those of [the functions that are generated for `data` classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html) which you actually need.

Comment: Thanks @hotkey! I like the suggestion with interfaces!